# Происхождение фамилии

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Может быть, вопрос глупый, но меня всегда интересовало происхождение фамилии великого композитора Модеста Мусоргского. Если бы в фамилии не было буквы Г, было бы понятно, фамилия происходит от слова "мусор". Или Г было именно для того, чтобы не возникало таких ассоциаций?

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, а что, принять ответ может не только его автор? Вы, я смотрю, часто это делаете за них!   

Кстати, этот вопрос спорный, ответы противоречат друг другу. Почему же Вы сами выбираете тот, который Вам понравился? Может, оставить это автору?

Comment: Естественно, модератор может принять ответ.
Должен ли он это делать и когда - другой вопрос.
Насколько понимаю, этот форум несколько отличается по задумке от всяких ответах на мэйл.ру и подобных проектов.
Помимо личных предпочтений автора оценивается ещё и научная достоверность, коллективный разум.

А ответ принимается тот, в котором наиболее полно представлены все версии. Впрочем, в конкретном случае не буду настаивать. Тут история действительно темная и ответа как такового я не знаю.

Comment: Мой вопрос, был , конечо, риторическим. Просто мягкая форма несогласия с действиями модератора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку - это руссифицированный вариант польской фамилии МусОргский или МусОржский.
В польском русскому р часто соответвует рж, причем графически это рж может передаваться как обычное р (латинское r). В польских источниках многочислены всякие МусОрские, МусЕрские, МосЕрские и проч. С учетом смоленских корней композитора польское влияние никак нельзя исключить. К сожалению, значения этих основ на польском мне неизвестны.

Впрочем, есть и другие мнения.

*Му́соргские — дворянский род, происходящий от князей Смоленских, из рода Монастырёвых. Роман Васильевич Монастырёв, по прозвищу Мусорга, был родоначальником Мусоргских. Пётр Иванович Мусоргский был воеводой в Старице (1620). Из этого рода происходил композитор Модест Петрович Мусоргский. Род внесён в VI ч. родословной книги Псковской губернии. Ветвью рода Мусоргских является дворянская фамилия Сапоговых.*
(вики)
По другим источникам эта история "Мусорги" с начала и до конца выдумана самим Мусоргским.

Comment: Вот мне подсказывают, что "мусорга" в псковских говорах, возможно,  веник. Но недостоверно.

Comment: Давайте будем снисходительны к Мусоргскому. Он все-таки не сын турецкоподданного. Кое-чем русскую культуру обогатил. Пусть даже если он и придумал историю своей фамилии. Быть "служителем муз" композитору приятнее, чем иметь  с веником.:-)

Answer (score 1):

Известно, что композитор часто возмущался тем, что многие произносилиего фамилию с ударением на втором слоге: Мус**о**ргский, в то время как он сам произносил ее с ударением на первом слоге: М**у**соргский, основываясь на прозвище одного из своих предков - М**у**сорги, что в переводе с греческого означает 'преданный музам', т.е. 'преданный искусству'. Следовательно, ваши подозрения беспочвенны. Фамилия самая творческая.

Comment: "композитор часто возмущался тем, что многие произносилиего фамилию с ударением на втором слоге: Мусоргский, в то время как он сам произносил ее с ударением на первом слоге..."

По другим источникам - как раз наоборот )))


Музыкант по-речески - μουσικός (Мусикос), никаких Р там и впомине нету.

Answer (score 0):

Родоначальником знаменитого композитора был Роман Васильевич, по прозвищу Мусорга. В фамилии ударение изменилось. 'Мусургос' по-гречески - певец, музыкант.

Answer (score 0):

Ответы противоречивые. Если фамилия древняя - откуда в ней греческие корни? Насколько я знаю, такого рода фамилии (или их русские кальки) давались особам духовного звания. Впрочем, музы сюда не очень подходят.

А когда мог жить этот "Роман Васильевич Монастырёв, по прозвищу Мусорга"? И как он был связан с музами?

Comment: Да этот самый Мусорга чуть не при Рюрике служил.
Не "особам духовного звания", а обыкновеннвм семинаристам дабы облагозвучить их и различать десятоу Ивановых. Это потом уже эти семинаристы становильсь особами.